# How can I implement a generic component and subclass it for specific model in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component for a generic dialog window. It has no model, and a handful of slots for the title, the center, and the buttons.

Now I want to populate this dialog with a form. Obviously the details of the model, and the content, are specific to the form contained in, as well as the general behavior (e.g. validation etc).

What is the preferred Vue approach to handle this requirement?

Comment: Why not just put the form component in the center slot of the dialog window component?

Comment: [Favor composition over inheritance](https://codingdelight.com/2014/01/16/favor-composition-over-inheritance-part-1/)

Comment: @RoyJ that is completely useless in addressing my problem

Comment: @thanksd because I want to reuse the dialog component as a generic component. if I do so, I am binding the dialog to a specific form subcomponent.

Comment: no, you'd still have two components: generic dialog and form. And in a view where you want a form in the dialog, you'd import both components and put the form component tag in the center slot of the generic dialog

Comment: @thanksd that could actually work... let me try

Comment: @thanksd it seems to work. Please make it as an answer so I can mark it as good.

Comment: There's also `Vue.extend()`, `mixins`, etc. I don't think there is a *preferred* approach that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your dialog component is just a template with slots, it seems like it would be easiest to use both the generic dialog component and the form component in your template and then simply put the form component tag in the dialog component's center slot:

```
<template>
  <my-generic-dialog>
    <template slot="center">
      <my-form></my-form>
    </template>
  </my-generic-dialog>
</template>
```

---

As Bert Evans mentioned in his comment, if you were looking for a way to separate out general *functionality* of a vue component, you could either use [`Vue.extend()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend), or [Vue `mixins`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).